# want to split string to based on pattern to get only lots values in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

example;
string=ALL OF LOT 3 IN BLOCK 41 AND THOSE PORTIONS OF LOTS 1 AND 2 IN SAID BLOCK 41, LYING SOUTH OF A LINE DRAWN PARALLEL WITH AND 1320 FEET SOUTH OF THE NORTH LINE OF PUEBLO LOT 1193, ALL OF MORENO, IN THE CITY OF SAN DIEGO, COUNTY OF SAN DIEGO, STATE OF CALIFORNIA,

answer=LOTS 1 AND 2

plzz help.

Comment: Can you please clarify your actual question? It is unclear what you are looking for. How do you know it's lots 1 and 2, but not 3?

Comment: i want only lots number from the given string. don't want lot

Comment: ill give another example

Comment: srting:LOTS 1, 2 AND THE NORTH 17 FEET OF LOT 3, BLOCK 3. OAK PARK SUBDIVISION TO THE CITY OF CARROLL, CARROLL COUNTY, IOWA                                                                                       
   answer:LOTS 1, 2

Comment: This is a prime example of why original effort is so important on SO. If you showed what you tried and explained '*it worked on [this] but not on [these]*' then someone would have a hope of pointing you in the right direction. As it is, your question is without original effort and shows a single example while the narrative contradicts your own comment describing the desired output. If you cannot be bothered to write a reasonable question, why would **anyone** volunteer to help you? This isn't an online game of Twenty Questions.

Comment: @Jeeped Doh! :-)

Comment: new to vba , so confused how to start. thats why i asked without trying . if you can please help or else :-)

Comment: @qwe The problem is not your knowledge of VBA. In order to program in any language, you first need to develop a clear and unambiguous description of what you want to do.  Your question and examples do not yet reflect that. Once you can communicate clear specifications, then writing code becomes much simpler.  Aim for an explanation that someone with zero knowledge of anything about you or your work or environment can easily understand.

Comment: @qwe, that second example isn't helpful at all. You are trying to get me to infer your logic. What I want is for you to explicitly tell me the logic. Again, I have no idea why it's lots 1 and 2, but not 3.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Dim RE As Object
Dim strig As String

Set w = ThisWorkbook
Set wa = w.Sheets("Main")

j = wa.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

```
For k = 1 To j
    Set RE = New RegExp
    strig = Range("a" & k).Value

    RE.Pattern = "(LOTS) (\d+)(\,) (\d+)|(LOTS) (\d+) (AND) (\d+)"
    RE.Global = True
    RE.IgnoreCase = True
    Set matches = RE.Execute(strig)

    For Each Item In matches
        If matches.Count <> 0 Then
        On Error Resume Next
        regEx = matches.Item(0)

        a = Trim(regEx)
        regEx = ""

        End If
    Next Item


    Range("b" & k).Value = a
    a = ""
Next k
```

Comment: got the answer @jeeped

Comment: thnx @kyle for your effort